# How to execute complex Javascript code?

Tags: javascript, ruby, selenium, watir

```
access = 'Product Name'
path = "//span[contains(text(), '#{access}')]/parent::*[1]/preceding-sibling::input[1]"
jscript = <<EOF
          function setCheckboxes(path){
var cbx = document.evaluate(path, document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue;
cbx.click()};
setCheckboxes("#{path}");
EOF
@browser.execute_script jscript
```

When I run this script, I get an error:

```
Selenium::WebDriver::Error::JavascriptError: JavaScript error
```

There are no issues on javascript or xpath. The issue is with the execution.
Could you please help me out to figure out what is wrong?

Comment: what is the full stack trace? Actually, that looks like it comes from an error in the driver. 1. Run your test with $DEBUG = true and paste the post & response for the executeScript. 2. What browser is this? Does it fail on other browsers? 3. Why do you need to do this in Javascript? Typically it is a bad idea. :)

Comment: Hi Titus, it is on IE, I need to do this way, it is much faster, since there is going to be an array of products (about 400) and seting checkboxes using watir is much slower.

Comment: Shot in the dark, but I wonder if it has to do with the interpolation of the `path` variable (i.e. `setCheckboxes("#{path}");`).  Per the [`documentation`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/doc/syntax/literals_rdoc.html#label-Here+Documents), here documents allow for interpolation.  So, the double-quotes may not be needed.

Comment: I tried to run the test on firefox, it works, but on IE it throws error. I tried to remove quotes, did not help.

Comment: Does that JavaScript work when you execute it in IE on a normal page that has that code (rather than injecting it using Watir)? I have always been under the impression that IE does not support XPath - ie `document.evaluate` is not supported. This [MSN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/evaluate) suggest that there is still no support.

Comment: @JustinKo you were right, it works on Firefox and does not work on IE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that IE does not support XPath - ie `document.evaluate` is not supported (see the [MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/evaluate)).

You will need to change the script so that it uses methods supported by IE. There are two general approaches:

1. Locate the elements using Watir and then click the element using `execute_script` or
2. Locate and click the element using `execute_script`.

Given an HTML page with 400 checkboxes like:

```
<input type="checkbox">
<label>
  <span>Product Name</span>
</label>
```

We can benchmark the various approaches:

```
def browser_setup
  browser = Watir::Browser.new :ie
  browser.goto 'file:///C:/test/page.htm'
  browser
end

Benchmark.bm do |x|
  x.report("Locate and click via standard methods:") do
    browser = browser_setup
    browser.checkboxes.each(&:click)
  end

  x.report("Locate via standard methods and click via script:") do
    browser = browser_setup
    browser.checkboxes.each do |checkbox|
      browser.execute_script('arguments[0].click();', checkbox)
    end
  end

  x.report("Locate and click via script:") do
    access = 'Product Name'
    check_all = %Q{
      all_spans = document.getElementsByTagName("span")
      for (var i = 0, max = all_spans.length; i < max; i++){
        if (all_spans[i].innerText.indexOf("#{access}") > -1){
           var parent = all_spans[i].parentElement;

           var preceding_sibling = parent.previousSibling;
           while(preceding_sibling && preceding_sibling.nodeType != 1 && preceding_sibling.tagName != "input") {
             preceding_sibling = preceding_sibling.previousSibling;
           }
         preceding_sibling.click();
        }
      }
    }

    browser = browser_setup
    browser.execute_script(check_all)
  end
end
```

Which gives the results:

```
                                                         user     system      total        real
Locate and click via standard methods:               0.109000   0.171000   0.280000 (207.682750)
Locate via standard methods and click via script:    0.063000   0.031000   0.094000 ( 58.156400)
Locate and click via script:                         0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  2.516400)
```

From the results, we can see that this large page performs slowly when using just the standard Watir checkbox methods. The performance is significantly improved by directly clicking the elements with `execute_script`. The checking becomes almost instantaneous when both the locating and clicking is done via `execute_script`.

Comment: That was my conclusion as well and I have implemented checking checkboxes using javascript and executing it on browser